# VBA code for custom ribbon tool errors in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon-control

The code that follows **works perfectly in Excel 2013 and prior**, but upon installing Excel 2016 (via Office 365 subscription) and opening one of my workbooks with custom ribbon tools, I get a "Can't find Library" error. ( there are no missing references)

Here is one sample Sub (dropdown control in ribbon) where the error pops up.
The error is on the Call, where it doesn't like returnedVal.

```
'Callback for rxdrdnAcctName onAction
Sub rxdrdnAcctName_Click(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Integer)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call rxDropDownItemLabel(control, index, returnedVal)    

    Sheets("Tables").Range("AcctNametoPlot").Value = returnedVal
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        LogError(Now & "...RibbonTool--> " & Err.Description)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the code for the sub getting called

```
'Callback for rxdrdnAcctName getItemLabel
Sub rxDropDownItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)
    Dim varItems As Variant
    If (control.id = "rxdrdnAcctName" Or control.id = "rxdrdnNewAcctName") Then
        varItems = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("SortedAcctList").Value
    ElseIf (control.id = "rxdrdnYear" Or control.id = "rxdrdnNewAcctYear") Then
        varItems = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("YearsList").Value
    ElseIf control.id = "rxdrdnMonth" Then
        varItems = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("MonthNames").Value
    ElseIf control.id = "rxdrdnCommod" Then
        varItems = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("CommodityPLNamesList").Value
    ElseIf control.id = "rxdrdnSheetSelectName" Then
        varItems = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Range("AllSheetsNames").Value
    End If
    returnedVal = varItems(index + 1, 1)
End Sub
```

What has changed in Excel 2016 (for customizing the ribbon) that has broken this code?

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` to all modules, does your code compile? (Debug / Compile) -- And which line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: @Andre...added more info in original post. I always use Option Explicit in every module.

Comment: Where is `returnedVal` declared before you try and pass it to the `rxDropDownItemLabel` routine?

Comment: @Rory...Private returnedVal as String...declared at top of module...but your missing the point, this code works fine in Excel 2007-2013

Comment: Custom ribbon tool doesn't work with office -16.  Use other tools.

Comment: Uh, doesn't it? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-ribbon-in-Office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31

Comment: Doesn't seem like the underlying CustomUI XML spec has changed or become incompatible with the release of 2016 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944957(v=office.12).aspx)